# Can TFS work with a local user account?

Tags: jenkins, tfs

I'm trying to use the [Jenkins TFS Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin) and have trouble authenticating. I saw that user on the TFS administration, and gave it permissions on my project.
I've created a local user account (via Local Users and Groups) - `TfsServer\TfsUserAdmin`, and I'm trying to use it to authenticate against the TFS server.

I able able to use the name and password of the user. For example this works (though it prints an empty list):

```
tf workspaces -format:brief -server:http://TfsServer:8080/tfs/Redacted_Collection -login:TfsServer\TfsUserAdmin,RedactedPassword
```

If I change the password on the above command I get an error, so authentication does work.

The next command is:

```
tf workspace -new "RedactedWorkspaceName;" -noprompt -server:http://TfsServer:8080/tfs/Redacted_Collection -login:TfsServer\TfsUserAdmin,RedactedPassword
```

This fails with the error:

```
TF14045: The identity TfsServer\TfsUserAdmin is not a recognized identity.
```

I don't think I can change these commands, they are created by the plugin.

I've found people with similar errors, but none of them had the user name at the error - only a GUID or the server name.

Can I work with TFS and a local user?

Comment: Is your TFS joined to the domain?

Comment: @MrHinsh - The TFS server is on *a* domain, but the Jenkins server is on another domain. There are no shared users, and we can't easily create users on the TFS's domain.

Comment: For the record: I was unable to get a local user to work, and we've eventually got IT to create an Active Directory user.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely need to use Shadow Accounts to get your Jenkins server to talk to TFS...

Create a local user on both your TFS server and your Jenkins server with the same Username & Passowrd. Then use that account to authenticate.

This is the only way to get cross domain coms working without trust and is a feature of Windows & AD. If your org has disabled it you will need to look at creating a trust relationship between your domains.

Comment: Thanks! Can I do that? I need to authenticate using the computer name as a domain: `TfsServer\TfsUserAdmin` - How can I create a user on the Jenkins server with the same name? Wouldn't it be `JenkinsServer\TfsUserAdmin`?

Comment: Windows take care of it. You might need to do ".\TfsUserAdmin", but that is not my experience.

Comment: That didn't work for me. I did discover something interesting (to me) - I can use *anything* as the domain (Anything\TfsUserAdmin), and it'd work. Weird. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: If it did not work then it I'd blocked. You need domain admin help.